# How to find the closest pixel points indexes of one RGB list from another RGB list?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have been working for some Image Processing Task. I have provided all details what I want to do below.

## **What I intend to do:**

I have two lists

**colorlist** = around 500 rgb values (From picture 1 which I already have)

**color** = around 1200 or more RGB values (From picture 2 which I have also)

***Note:** Above lists can vary their size like **colorlist** can be sometimes bigger than **color***

Now I want to find all the elements of **color** to get its closest pixel values in **colorlist** then return the closest pixel values in a form of list [suppose **list_1**] and finally return the indexes of that list [**list_1**] from Picture 2 whole Image RGB List.

**For Example:**

```
picture2 = 
[[ 59 218 186]
 [161 144 250]
 [133 165 249]
 [135 125 125]
 ...
 [59  58 145]
 [153  144 155]
 [ 61 225  87]
 [153 149  63]]

colorlist = 

[[ 59 218 186]
 [161 144 250]
 [133 165 249]
 ...
 [155  58 184]
 [ 61 225  87]
 [153 149  63]]

color = 

[[201 224 194]
 [121  93 158]
 [ 99 143 153]
 ...
 [193  67 171]
 [ 80  49  94]
 [125 121 219]]


#Suppose these two values are closest found  in color array from colorlist
list1 = [(161, 144, 250), (133, 165, 249) ] 



index = [2 , 3] #Found from picture2 whole image array

###the index here is assumed for demonstration it can be larger or different from colorlist
```

## **What I tried:**

**Method 1:** Using numpy linalg norm

```
def closest_points(color,colorlist):
  for x in range (0, len(color):
    dist = np.linalg.norm(colorlist - color[x], axis=1)
    tmp = colorlist[np.argmin(dist)]
    list1.append(tmp)
  return list1
```

**ERROR THROWS:**
Same as Method 2 (Dimension Error)

**Method 2:** Using Scipy KDTree

```
def closest_points(color,colorlist):
  for x in range (0, len(color):
    tree = sp.KDTree(colorlist)
    tmp = colorlist[tree.query(color[x])[1]]
    list1.append(tmp)
  return list1
```

**ERROR THROWS:**

```
super().__init__(data, leafsize, compact_nodes, copy_data,
File "_ckdtree.pyx", line 560, in scipy.spatial._ckdtree.cKDTree.__init__
ValueError: data must be 2 dimensions
```

**Method 3:**

```
def closest_points(rgb,newlist):
    r, g, b = rgb
    color_diffs = []
    for x in newlist:
        cr, cg, cb = x
        color_diff = math.sqrt((r - cr)**2 + (g - cg)**2 + (b - cb)**2)
        color_diffs.append((color_diff, x))
    return min(color_diffs)[1]

for x in range (0, len(color)):
    
    tmp = closest_color(color[x],colorlist)
    list1.append(tmp)
```

**ERROR THROWS:**

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Hope my question is clear. Thanks for the help !

Comment: What's the problem with the 3 proposed methods? Method 2 should be faster than the other ones for large color lists.

Comment: Why are you not happy with your solutions?  (Your approaches with using some distance measure sounds reasonable)

Comment: I have updated already what type of error throws in my approaches. Please check the details again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution of it by myself. In method 2 there is no need to iterate.

```
def closest_points(color,colorlist): 
  tree = sp.KDTree(colorlist)
  tmp = colorlist[tree.query(color)[1]]
return tmp
```